# category names for facet plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a facet plot in R and I want to give a subtitle to the different columns and the different rows of the plot.
I created an example based on the mpg data.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl) + 
    scale_y_continuous("cty", 
                   sec.axis = sec_axis(~., breaks=NULL, name = "drv")) +
    ggtitle("plot from mpg", subtitle="cyl")
```

This already does what I want. The label on the bottom describes the x-axis on each of the little plots. The label on the top describes what the 4 columns represent. The label on the left describes the y-axis on the little plots and the label on the right describes the rows of the plot.

However, I kind of cheated. The label on the top is actually a subtitle of the plot and the label on the right is created through a secondary axis. I had to put breaks=NULL to hide the secondary axis and just display its name. This also creates lots of warning messages.

Is there a proper way with facet_grid to do what I want?

**Edit:** I noticed that my code example was incomplete and not functional. I corrected it, hopefully it works now.